# YouTube/GData API responding with "Missing start boundary"

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I'm getting errors when trying to upload to YouTube using the Java client/api. I hadn't tested it in a while, but it was working, so I'm not sure what caused it to stop.

As far as I can tell, everything looks ok, but YouTube continually responds with "Missing start boundary" when I try and upload a new video.

I'm really at a loss as to what could be causing this. I ended up running through a proxy to capture this information, hopefully it is helpful in figuring out why I'm getting this.

The request…

```
POST /feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary="----=_Part_2_1952419521.1368370735234"
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=<removed>
User-Agent: service-test YouTube-Java/1.0 GData-Java/1.47.1(gzip)
X-GData-Key: key=<removed>
X-GData-Client: service-test
Slug: Screen.Recording.m4v
Accept-Encoding: gzip
GData-Version: 2.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

------=_Part_2_1952419521.1368370735234
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><app:control xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'><app:draft>yes</app:draft><yt:incomplete/></app:control><atom:category xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/><atom:content xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' type='video/mp4'/><media:group><media:title type='plain'>Screen.Recording.m4v</media:title></media:group><yt:accessControl permission='denied' action='list'/></entry>
------=_Part_2_1952419521.1368370735234
Content-Type: video/mp4

<removed video content>

------=_Part_2_1952419521.1368370735234--
```

And the response…

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-GData-User-Country: US
Content-Type: application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 12 May 2013 14:58:55 GMT
Expires: Sun, 12 May 2013 14:58:55 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE

<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
    <error>
        <domain>GData</domain>
        <code>InvalidEntryException</code>
        <internalReason>Missing start boundary</internalReason>
    </error>
</errors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody else will run into this problem, but just for the sake of posterity and to help anyone else out if they are as dumb as me and come across this. I was uploading to the wrong URL. The path is right, but I was uploading to the wrong domain. The domain for uploading is different than all the other gdata calls.

It is

```
uploads.gdata.youtube.com
```

instead of

```
gdata.youtube.com
```